# How to present email marketing in a portfolio?

Tags: designers, portfolio, e-mail

Print design is easy to present. Web design is a little more complicated but not too bad. How do you all suggest presenting Emails to a client? Forward them the actual emails? Save them as .PDFs / Images? Something else entirely?

Comment: I have the same question. I have some rather long retail emails and want to show off both the body and the head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way you would a web page -- images showing the page design. HTML emails *are* just web pages coded with less-modern methods. You should be able to load any HTML email in a web browser window and take a screenshot of it. If the email contains application-specific tags like {openemailmarker} or {unsubscribehyperlink}, you may need to generate those to replace the tags.

If you want to display the *content* more than the design, or if the email is more text -based than visually based, just displaying the text, well formatted, would be sufficient.

Emails traditionally have absolutely no "functionality" other than clicking internal links. In reality showing emails is often easier than showing web sites because it's traditionally a single page and merely takes a single image to show the design.

If there is a series of emails to constitute a campaign, then I'd present a series of images showing the sales path.

You could be all fancy and create some generic email image "chrome" or frame to make the content appear as if it is within an email client. However, I find that often that's overkill and some clients may see that framing as actually *part of the design*. The framing often carries more confusion than benefit with it.

Comment: Yup, and (as with web pages), if a selling point is that you do responsive (email) design, showing the same design on a selection of differently sized devices usually goes down well

Comment: You'll also want to provide value-add information about yourself, by mentioning the team-work involved, why the design choices were correct for the constraints, the outcome of the email campaign, and so on. This part of your portfolio needs to be about more than just "I made a pretty email. See!" Expose the value you added, by using words in the description, or by adding labels directly over the image. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first option is a webpage. Probably some simulted screensshoots of a desktop browser or a mobile device.

I mean simulated so you do not need to mask all your mails from your inbox.

Comment: That's an important point, @Rafael: respect confidentiality if using an image of a real email!